# best way to take text input up to 2000 character android applicaiton

Tags: android, android-activity, alert

My application should be able to show some dialog or activity in order to take text input from user. With OK and CANCEL button

I tried 2 ways 
1. alert dialog with custom layout i.e. edittext, ok and cancel button
But once user clicks ok, onClick() event accepts only final string. And alert dialog is called from Main activity but code written in Utils class say Utils.showDialog().

Once dialog gets data, I need to pass the edit text string back to MainActivity from where util.showdialog() is called.

Other method 
2. From MainActivity started new activity with edit text, ok and cancel layout. once user clicks ok, in activity, I am getting string and processing it. Layout is is edit text below that OK and CANCEL button.

One problem with this is, I am limiting number of characters to 2000 and when I keep entering text more than screen of mobile (say 5 inch), OK cancel button are going down and unable to access OK and CANCEL button.

If i need to use 2nd method, I should be able to fix OK and CANCEL button at bottom and edit text above should be able to move up and down.

How can I achieve this and which one is appropriate ?

Comment: You could just programmatically fix the dialog size:

alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.

Answer (score 1):

your layout should be something like this for 2nd method

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="2000" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this layout but when data enters beyond screen limit, OK and cancel  buttons are gone down and not visible. I want both buttons should be visible at bottom edit text view should be able to scroll. With above edit text is scrollable but buttons stop visible beyond couple of lines enter.

Comment: @Sudarshansridhar Add an `android:id` attribute to your `LinearLayout`, call it something like `linearLayoutId`, then add the following line to `ScrollView` - `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutId"`